# HTML Authentication on Java doesn't work

Tags: java, http, authentication

I am trying to send a website my username or password using some jar file from Apache and trying to read everything from the website with the help of my method "loadpage".

It doesn't work. After I execute my method "loadpage". I still get the Streams from the main page, which I don't need to be logged in. I want to have Streams after i am logged in.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope("https://justawebsite", 8080),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username","password"));

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://justawebsite");

            System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
            }
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } finally {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
```

I tried it also without the help of some jarfile from Apache.

```
public  void LogIn(String url1) throws Exception{
        URL url = new URL(url1);

        String userPassword = "username"+":"+"password";
        String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode (userPassword.getBytes());
        //con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+getSid());

        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        //con.connect();
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + encoding);


        con.connect();

    }
```

My Method Loadpage: it works because I tried it with some other websites, which don't need an authentication.

public  String loadPage(String url) throws Exception {

```
    URLConnection con = new URL(url).openConnection();
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while((line=in.readLine())!= null){
        buffer.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    return buffer.toString();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "you need to be _logged in_"? What authentication  method does the website use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actuualy what i did was correct. I found the Solution just with luck.I don't know why, but i had to write `in.readLine();` one time before the

```
in.readLine();

while((line=in.readLine()) != null){
buffer.append(line);
}
in.close()
```

to get the Streams after i was logged in. If i dont do this line before While.. i get the Streams before i was logged in, allthough i was logged in.

Comment: You should accept your own solution if that was the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should first check which authentication type is the website using as pointed out by Behe, as there are different [Web Authentication Types](http://www.ehow.com/list_6659435_authentication-types.html).

Your first example is using Basic Authentication, but the website is probably expecting some kind of Form Based Authentication.

If latest is your case, you should check this [Client HTTP Programming Primer](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/primer.html) which includes

> - enter username and password in a web form and hit the "login" button